# Hoeffding's Inequality Probability $>1$

Tags: probability

in one of the courses the professor said that Hoeffding's Inequality equation is this
[image]
but for me that does not make any sense as it can be greater than $1.$

For example, assume

$$\varepsilon = 0.00001$$

$$N = 1000$$

That will make the probability $\leq 2( e^{-2\cdot 0.0000000001\cdot 1000}) = 2\cdot 0.999999 = 1.99999.$

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is wrong - if the right hand side is greater than $1$, it just means that the inequality is pointless in that case, since all probabilities are less than or equal to $1$.